# Basic authentication with header - Javascript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors, basic-authentication, adyen

I am trying to access Adyen test API that requires basic authentication credentials. https://docs.adyen.com/developers/ecommerce-integration

My credentials work when accessing the API page through browser.
[image: Authentication]

But I get an ***401 Unauthorized*** response when trying to access the API with XMLHttpRequest POST request.

**Javascript Code**

```
var url = "https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/servlet/Payment/v25/authorise";

var username = "ws@Company.CompanyName";
var password = "J}5fJ6+?e6&lh/Zb0>r5y2W5t";
var base64Credentials = btoa(username+":"+password);

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);

var requestParams = XXXXXXXX;
xhttp.send(requestParams);
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PAL is a Payment Authorisation API. You **never** want to call it from a browser. You only want to expose your username and password to send in payments in your backend code.

In Client-side encryption, the encryption is done in the browser. You then send the encrypted data to your own server. On your server you then create a payment authorization request (of which the encrypted data is one of the elements, along side payment amount, etc).

If you would be able to manage to make this run from your browser, your end solution will allow your shoppers to change amounts, currency's, payment meta data etc from the JavaScript layer. This should never be the case.

The authorization is for that reason part of the "Server side" integration part of documentation: https://docs.adyen.com/developers/ecommerce-integration?ecommerce=ecommerce-integration#serverside

Depending on your server side landscape the CURL implementation in your favorite language differs, but most of the time are easy to find.

Kind regards,

Arnoud

Answer (score 6):

That screenshot shows “**Request Method:** OPTIONS”, which indicates the details displayed are for a [CORS preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) automatically made by your browser—not for your `POST`.

Your browser doesn’t (and can’t) send the `Authorization` header when it makes that `OPTIONS` request, and that causes the preflight to fail, so the browser never moves on to trying your `POST`.

As long as `https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/servlet/Payment/v25/authorise` requires authentication for `OPTIONS` requests, there’s no way you can make a successful `POST` to it.

The reason is because what’s happening here is this:

1. Your code tells your browser it wants to send a request with the `Authorization` header.
2. Your browser says, OK, requests with the `Authorization` header require me to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` to make sure the server allows requests with that header.
3. Your browser sends the `OPTIONS` request to the server **without the `Authorization` header**—because the whole purpose of the `OPTIONS` check is to see if it’s OK to send that.
4. That server sees the `OPTIONS` request but instead of responding to it in a way that indicates it allows `Authorization` in requests, it rejects it with a 401 since it lacks that header.
5. Your browser expects a 200 or 204 response for the CORS preflight but instead gets that 401 response. So your browser stops right there and never tries the `POST` request from your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
But there should be a way to access the api though.?

Comment: You can always access it from backend code, but yeah if it's otherwise returning the right Access-Control headers, it seems like it's also intended to be accessed from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser. But that doesn't mean it actually can be. Their docs show no examples of using it from frontend JavaScript, and there's no way a preflight will ever work if it requires authorization like that